# smartgit and ksdiff integration

Tags: smartgit, kaleidoscope

I'd like using the Kaleidoscope/ksdiff as my conflict solver in smartgit. I've tried configuring by myself but I can't. So, what is the line instruction that I need to put at arguments input on edit conflict solver configuration?

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The required configuration to integrate Kaleidoscope/ksdiff with smartgit is that:

```
--merge --output ${mergedFile} --base ${baseFile} -- ${leftFile} --snapshot ${rightFile} --snapshot
```

just put it on arguments field and the magic will happen :)